# Do hidden html radio buttons still contain and submit their value?

Tags: html, forms

If I have an HTML radio button with `hidden=true`, does the button still contain its value and if it's in a form does it submit this value when the form is submitted?

Another way of asking this is, does the hidden attribute do any behind the scene changes (backend) or is it purely a visual difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All hidden form elements retain their information and it is submitted with the form. This is true if the input type is hidden, the element is hidden through CSS, or the HTML5 hidden attribute. The hiding is purely visual.

Comment: I remember some old version of Safari not submitting fields hidden with `display: none`. But I believe very few people should still be using those browsers these days...

Comment: Truth, I think it had something to do with security. Given that Safari auto updates pretty easily, I doubt there's a noticeable market share there.